# 'rbind' and 'lapply' work just fine, unless I need to append the filename

Tags: r, lapply, rbind

I'm reading some csv files to create a dataframe, and append an additional column to it with the file name, using the following code:

```
wd <- "Working directory"
file_list <- list.files(wd)

### Function: read data ###
read_data <- function(file){
  d <- read.csv(paste(wd,file,sep=""), stringsAsFactors = FALSE, strip.white = TRUE, na.strings = c("NA","")); # read in every file in the working directory
  d$FileName <- substr(file,20,29); # append part of file name 
  d # return the dataframe
}

### Call rbind: merge data ###
df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(file_list,read_data))
```

But this error comes up:

```
 Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "FileName", value = "2016010209") : 
  replacement has 1 row, data has 0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Cheers

Comment: Could the file corresponding to "2016010209" possibly contain only a header and no data?

Comment: Try adding a `print` or `message` statement into your `read_data` function to first pinpoint which file is causing problems. Inspect that file that is indeed in the form you expect it to be.

Comment: IMHO it is better to set the working directory `setwd(wd)`. In that case have to change you script in some parts.

Comment: OMG, you (Roland and Roman) are right! The file was corrupted (so empty)!

Answer (score 0):

Always check the data! The file was corrupted, therefore empty!
Thanks for your help!